# C# - Virtual, Override - Execution Path

Tags: c#, oop

```
class zzz
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        yyy a = new vvv();
        xxx b = new vvv();
        www c = new vvv();
        vvv d = new vvv();

        a.pqr();
        b.pqr();
        c.pqr();
        d.pqr();
    }
}
class yyy
{
    public virtual void pqr()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("yyy pqr");
    }
}
class xxx : yyy
{
    public override void pqr()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("xxx pqr");
    }
}
class www : xxx
{
    public override void pqr()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("www pqr");
    }
}
class vvv : www
{
    public override void pqr()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("vvv pqr");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 vvv pqr
 vvv pqr
 vvv pqr
 vvv pqr
```

I know the question i am going to ask will earn me some down votes. But i don't have any other choice. Can someone help me to understand execution path of this code?
What i was thinking that a.pqr() will stop at "xxx pqr", But i was wrong. And wrong for others too.

I failed to elaborate my problem so i am trying it again.

1. if i take a.pqr() into consideration:

   Execution will start from yyy [What i think, need to be corrected.] 
   yyy.pqr() is virtual now it will look at xxx.pqr() which is override. Shouldn't it stop here?
   or it will traverse to www.pqr() because xxx.pqr() is carrying virtual properties      from yyy(base class) and it will end up at vvv.pqr() [Actual type] ??
2. For c.pqr() :

   can i get help to understand why does it call "vvv pqr"? 
   Its override. Still there is connection with its base? i looked at it its override so i thought answer would be "www pqr" because its not virtual it won't traverse,But it did. If i make www.pqr() new, output will be "www pqr" because its new and i don't have to look down. I am in dilemma with basic understanding.

Comment: *Why* would you expect it to stop at "xxx pqr"?

Comment: Naming the classes better would make it easy to understand.

Comment: What do you mean "stop"?  You have 4 different calls, each with a different path.

Comment: The code you've given actually prints "vvv pqr" four times, as I'd expect it to. Either you're not running the code you posted, or you're not getting the results you posted, or you're using a broken compiler or execution environment.

Comment: Nice variable names..

Comment: Obviously the variable names are placeholders, the focus should be on what the code does, not how things are named.

Comment: @AStacker: It wouldn't, it would give you "vvv", because you're creating four objects of type `vvv`.

Comment: @Stijn: Using conventional variable and method names makes it *easier* to focus on what the code does.

Comment: @Jon agree when the code is long, but this one is pretty short. I'll edit the question, since none of the three complainers bothered to do so.

Comment: @Stijn: That just makes it easier to follow the conventions, right? How hard would it have been for the OP to use PascalCased type and method names, for example?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It means for a.pqr(), it will start from yyy pqr=>xxx pqr=>www pqr => vvv pqr. But here yyy pqr is only virtual function exists.

Comment: @Stijn Not sure that edit was a good idea, now the answers don't make sense

Comment: @BenAaronson I guess they don't. Meh, reverting my edit.

Comment: @Stijn Could always edit the answers.

Comment: @AStacker: I don't understand your comment, I'm afraid. Until you can explain more about what you expected and why, it's going to be very hard to help you. That explanation should be in the *question*, not in  comments.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Sir, i have edited the question. I hope my explanation would be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You're working with virtual method dispatch. Since your method is virtual and you're never hiding it, it will always call the method body of the actual type, not the variable's type.

If you used `new` instead of `override`, it would print this:

```
yyy pqr
xxx pqr
www pqr
vvv pqr
```

The method called would be determined at compile-time - and in compile-time, you're working with the variable types, instead of the actual runtime types.

Which means that getting to your "answer" would require you to do this:

```
class www : xxx
{
    public new void pqr()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("www pqr");
    }
}
```

Now the virtual method "chain" is broken at `www` - the methods `yyy.pqr` and `xxx.pqr` are different virtual methods than `www.pqr` and `vvv.pqr`.

However, most likely, this is a very wrong behaviour, as it violates the object-oriented programming principles - the method called should *not* depend on the type of the variable, it should depend on the type of the object. This is why the compiler warns you if you hide methods without using `new`, and this is why you should only use `new` very sparingly - most often it would simply mean your object design is wrong.

Even so, your overrides actually throw away the whole code of the parent method. That usually isn't a very good practice - the more common pattern would be to call the parent method as part of the execution of the child method. For example:

```
class yyy
{
    public virtual void pqr()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("yyy pqr");
    }
}
class xxx : yyy
{
    public override void pqr()
    {
        base.pqr();

        System.Console.WriteLine("xxx pqr");
    }
}
class www : xxx
{
    public override void pqr()
    {
        base.pqr();

        System.Console.WriteLine("www pqr");
    }
}
class vvv : www
{
    public override void pqr()
    {
        base.pqr();

        System.Console.WriteLine("vvv pqr");
    }
}
```

Now if you call `new vvv().pqr()`, you'll get the following output:

```
yyy pqr
xxx pqr
www pqr
vvv pqr
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is declared virtual in `yyy`, and overridden in every descendant class. It's one method with lots of implementations, as far as the CLR is concerned. The compiler emits a call to that method, and at execution time the CLR will consider the *actual* type of the object that the method is called on, and execute the implementation which overrides it closest to that type.

From the C# 5 specification, section 10.6.3:

> In a virtual method invocation, the *run-time type* of the instance for which that invocation takes place determines the actual method implementation to invoke.
>
> ...
>
> For every virtual method declared in or inherited by a class, there exists a *most derived implementation* of the method with respect to that class. The most derived implementation of a virtual method M with respect to a class R is determined as follows:
>
> - If R contains the introducing virtual declaration of M, then this is the most derived implementation of M.
> - Otherwise, if R contains an override of M, then this is the most derived implementation of M.
> - Otherwise, the most derived implementation of M with respect to R is the same as the most derived implementation of M with respect to the direct base class of R.